# Android studio how to reference library?

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, android-studio

I made a library in intelliJ. It is a rest client that I want to import it in android project. I want to develop the library seperate in intelliJ since it lets me to test it without actual android app but just in console. When I want to the import library in the android studio I get an error. I tried all the ways of importing library (a lot of them are from SO). This is what I do:

I go to project structure, choose dependencies and add from folder in which I have .jar file that I made in intelliJ. In IntelliJ I did Artifact and then build it as .jar. I moved that to android studio and it does not work. Bellow is the error I get when trying to compile project in Android studio.

```
     Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'.
```

> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
>       C:\Users\Gregor\AppData\Local\Android\android-studio\sdk\build-tools\android-4.4.2\dx.bat --dex --output C:\Users\Gregor\AndroidStudioProjects\Perla\app\build\pre-dexed\debug\PerlaRestAPI-985193a1adafac50f74c01c1069cd74ce9c69b55.jar C:\Users\Gregor\AndroidStudioProjects\Perla\app\libs\PerlaRestAPI.jar
>   Error Code:
>       1
>   Output:
>       UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
>       com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: bad class file magic (cafebabe) or version (0034.0000)
>           at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse0(DirectClassFile.java:472)
>           at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse(DirectClassFile.java:406)
>           at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parseToInterfacesIfNecessary(DirectClassFile.java:388)
>           at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.getMagic(DirectClassFile.java:251)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:665)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:634)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$600(Main.java:78)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:572)
>           at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:284)
>           at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
>           at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:596)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:498)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:264)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:230)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:199)
>           at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:103)
>       ...while parsing api/Game.class
>       1 error; aborting

Comment: I solved a similar problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28922800/1339200

Answer (score 3):

Is your library in IntelliJ being compiled with Java 7? This may be what is causing the dex tool to fail. Android only supports Java 6.

**Edit: This is no longer true as of from Android 5.0, which now requires Java 7.**

Comment: Tjere are some java 7 features supported: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Using-sourceCompatibility-1.7

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the error message `bad class file magic (cafebabe) or version (0034.0000)` and took the following steps to successfully solve the problem:

- Set the language level in my Intellij module to 7
- Set the JAR to be compiled to my Android module's libs folder
- Right-clicked on the JAR then **Add as library**
- Set **sourceCompatibility** and **targetCompatibility** to `JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7` in the Android module's build.gradle compileOptions

One possible problem to watch out for your JAR file having dependencies which are compiled with a Java version not currently supported by Android.