# UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION adding new Module to Android Studio project

Tags: android, class, exception

Frustrating error after adding a simple Java Library (new Module in Android Studio). I've read many similar questions but cannot find any solution, anyone can help me?

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':KeepLinkMain:preDexDebug'.
```

> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
>       C:\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\19.1.0\dx.bat --dex --output C:...\AndroidStudioProjects\KeepLink\KeepLinkMain\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\KeepLinkLib-d6db361e6605649280566ee9a3143d04322844dc.jar C:...\AndroidStudioProjects\KeepLink\KeepLinkLib\build\libs\KeepLinkLib.jar
>   Error Code:
>       1
>   Output:
>       UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
>       com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: bad class file magic (cafebabe) or version (0034.0000)
>           at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse0(DirectClassFile.java:472)
>           at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse(DirectClassFile.java:406)
>           at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parseToInterfacesIfNecessary(DirectClassFile.java:388)
>           at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.getMagic(DirectClassFile.java:251)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:665)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:634)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$600(Main.java:78)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:572)
>           at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:284)
>           at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
>           at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:596)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:498)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:264)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:230)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:199)
>           at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:103)
>       ...while parsing com/rmpt/keeplinklib/Constants.class
>       1 error; aborting

Main module build.gradle file

```
    apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '19.1.0'
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName '1.0'
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
            debuggable false
            jniDebugBuild false
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        incremental true
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':KeepLinkLib')
    compile files('lib/gson-2.2.4.jar')
}
```

Java Library build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'java'
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar issue and was able to resolve it by adding the following lines to the Java library's build.gradle below the `apply plugin:` line:

```
sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
```

I also had to remove the `compileOptions` block from within the main module's build.gradle

Comment: That worked for me.  I'm not sure why I had changed it to 1_8, but it needs to be 1_7.

Answer (score 1):

For the experimental gradle edition, that uses a different syntax, you have to write it this way:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'
//apply plugin: 'java' //do not include this line
model {
    android {
        compileOptions.with {
            sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
            targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        }
        ... //rest of gradle code
    }
}
```